# Python Tkinter and loops

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, window

I am trying to write a program that would help me practice my vocabulary. Basically I want to have it display a window once every 30 minutes which contains the words i'm currently learning. Here's my code:

```
import time
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
date = time.ctime()
text = Text(window, width=40, height=10)
window.title("Active Recall Trainer")
text.insert("1.0", "here is my text to insert")
canvas = Canvas(window, width=750, height=500, bg="SpringGreen2")
window.configure(width=300, height=150)
canvas.create_text(30, 10, text="""VOCABULARY""", fill="red")

while True:
    time.sleep(60*30)
    window.mainloop()
    print("Loop Complete")
```

The problem i have with this code is that my `while True` loop only displays the window once and while it's running(the window, not the loop), it can't progress forward to the `print` function. It's only once i close the window that the loop progresses, but as i said before, it doesn't reopen the window ever again (it's going straight to print).

From what i read online the problem appears to be within the `mainloop()` call as it essentially creates a loop within a loop. Now, my question is that:
Are the any other ways of displaying a window using tkinter?
If not, is there a way to make it work as explained using that method?

I will be extremely grateful for any tips and solutions. Please note that my knowledge of python is still very poor and I might not understand the more complex terms, so please speak to me like i'm 4.

EDIT: I tried closing the window at the end of each loop, but that doesn't seem to work either. I tried both `quit()` and `destroy()` functions but neither works. When using destroy function, my powershell returns this:

```
PS C:\Users\PC> py ex36.py
End of the loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\ex36.py", line 43, in <module>
    window.destroy()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2368, in destroy
    self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed
```

whereas if i try using the `quit()`function, the loop keeps on going but doesn't ever reopen the window again after closing it.

EDIT 2: SOLVED!

```
import time
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

while True:
    window = Tk()

    # Window
    text = Text(window, width=40, height=10)
    window.title("Active Recall Trainer")
    text.insert("1.0", "here is my text to insert")
    canvas = Canvas(window, width=750, height=500, bg="SpringGreen2")
    window.configure(width=300, height=150)

    # TEXT
    canvas.create_text(30, 10, text="""VOCABULARY""", fill="red")

    window.configure(bg="lightgray")
    canvas.pack()

    # Window
    window.after(3000, window.mainloop())
    window.after(1000, window.quit())
```

Comment: use the after function instead of sleep.

Comment: _"From what i read online the problem appears to be within the mainloop() call as it essentially creates a loop within a loop."_ no, it's not a loop within a loop. It is a single loop that waits for events and then dispatches callbacks.

Comment: Your "SOLVED!" code doesn't work they way you think. You are not using `window.after` correctly. The way you're using it, `window.mainloop()` is called immediately, and the result is passed to `window.after`.

Comment: Comment out in line 3. When you close the window, it waits for 30 seconds and then the window reappears again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im also new to python and never touched tkinter. The code works as intended if you place all lines inside the while loop. Any downside to this?

Comment: Above paused the loop until window was closed. Found this thread about that:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63081795/opening-tkinter-window-pauses-rest-of-the-program